# Very slow Ethernet connexion on Ubuntu 20.4 Realtek

Tags: networking, drivers, ethernet, realtek

the network by cable don't work, some wifi connexion is reject, i can connect to iphone wifi connexion. It's a dual boot configuration (windows 10), on windows no problem with cable or wifi, only with Ubuntu 20.4.1, on network i have the best of : 1Ko/s download. the wifi with Iphone seems to be good at the beginning but after it's large latence to receive information (the page is slow and gmail don't work on firefox) thank you very much to help me

Answer (score 0):

sudo ethtool enp4s0
Settings for enp4s0:
Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
1000baseT/Full
Supported pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
Supported FEC modes: Not reported
Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
1000baseT/Full
Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full
Link partner advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
Link partner advertised FEC modes: Not reported
Speed: 1000Mb/s
Duplex: Full
Port: MII
PHYAD: 0
Transceiver: internal
Auto-negotiation: on
Supports Wake-on: pumbg
Wake-on: d
Current message level: 0x00000033 (51)
drv probe ifdown ifup
Link detected: yes

lspci | grep -i eth
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 11)

The Ethernet cable connexion is very poor, what can i do ? Thank you